# RadixSort и резкая просадка производительности на больших значениях

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Итак, есть следующая, немного сырая реализация поразрядной сортировки `radix.hpp`:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct element_t {
    unsigned char* key;
    T* element;
};

/**
 * @brief Сортирует сложные объекты ( структуры и классы ), которые можно представить в виде числогого
 *        ключа. Имеет сложность O(nw), где n - количество элементов и w - количество байт на ключ.
 * @param begin - указатель на начало массива
 * @param end - указатель на следующий за конечным элемент
 * @param out - куда положить результат. Указатель НЕ должен указывать начало сортируемого элемента
 *              ( т.е. не должен быть равен `begin` ).
 * @param keyFunc - функция, возвращающая числовой ключ для переданного значения. В параметр outkey
 *                  записывается выходной ключ, а в keylen длина ключа в байтах.
 * @param freeKeys - если `true`, то все ключи из keyFunc высвобождаются из памяти
*/
template <typename T>
void radixSort(T* begin, T* end, T* out, const std::function<void(T& element, void** outkey, uint32_t* keylen)> &keyFunc, bool freeKeys = false) {
    uint64_t arraySize = end - begin;
    uint32_t keySize = 0;

    // *************************************************
    // *                   ПОДГОТОВКА                  *
    // *************************************************

    // Одним new аллоцируется место для обоих массивов сразу
    // Работает немного быстрее, да и в кэш должно попадать охотнее
    element_t<T>* elements = new element_t<T>[arraySize * 2];
    element_t<T>* elementBuffer = elements + arraySize;

    uint32_t currentKeySize;

    // Генерируем пары элемент-ключ с помощью keyFunc

    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        element_t<T> &element = elements[i];

        keyFunc(begin[i], (void**)&element.key, &currentKeySize);
        keySize = std::max(keySize, currentKeySize);

        element.element = begin + i;
    }

    uint64_t counts[256];

    // *************************************************
    // *                  СОРТИРОВКА                   *
    // *************************************************

    for(uint32_t key = 0; key < keySize; key++) {
        memset(counts, 0, 256 * sizeof(uint64_t));

        // Конкрентно в этой реализации я сортирую значения по ключу ( текущему байту )
        // записью в `counts[i]` количества раз, сколько мне попался байт со значением
        // `i` в текущем положении ключа. Затем, я прохожусь по всем `counts` и для каждого
        // i-того элемента записываю в `counts[i]` сумму значений с 0 по i-ый элемент.
        // Теперь, отняв от каждого единицу, мы получим индекс крайнего правого индекса
        // для каждого из значений, а значит, мы можем пройтись по каждому значению и
        // записывать это значение в индекс, на который указывает `counts[i]`, параллельно
        // декрементируя `counts[i]` ( т.к. мы уже заняли один из индексов ).

        // Реализацию с похожей идеей можно нагуглить, но никакого адекватного объяснения
        // там нет, и понять это можно только доперев самому :/

        for(uint64_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            counts[elements[i].key[key]]++;
        }

        for(uint64_t i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
            counts[i] += counts[i - 1];
        }

        for(uint64_t i = arraySize; i > 0; i--) {
            uint64_t idx = elements[i - 1].key[key];

            // Декрементируем сначала, а не в конце, чтобы получить индексы,
            // начинающиеся с 0
            counts[idx]--;

            elementBuffer[counts[idx]] = elements[i - 1];
        }

        // После swap'а массив `elements` всегда будет содержать отсортированные значения по текущему
        // байту ключа.
        std::swap(elements, elementBuffer);
    }

    // Теперь, выводим отсортированный результат
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        out[i] = *elements[i].element;
    }

    if(freeKeys) {
        for(uint64_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            delete[] elements[i].key;
        }
    }

    delete[] elements;
}
```

Бенчмируется она топорным кодом, который для каждого размера массива просто прогоняет функцию 30000 раз, замеряет время каджого раза с помощью `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` и выводит среднее время:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include "radix.hpp" // тут реализация

const uint64_t samplesCount = 1000;

void keyConverter(uint32_t& element, void** key, uint32_t *keylen) {
    (*key) = (void*)&element;
    (*keylen) = sizeof(uint32_t);
}

int main() {
    std::function<void(uint32_t& element, void** outkey, uint32_t* keylen)> convFunc(keyConverter);

    uint64_t arraySize = 10;

    uint32_t *benchArray = new uint32_t[20000000];
    uint32_t *sortedArray = benchArray + 10000000;

    // От 1 до 7 ( не включительно ) степени десятки
    for(uint32_t sp = 1; sp < 7; sp++) {
        uint64_t totalTime = 0;

        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < samplesCount; i++) {
            // Вот этот цикл проходит 30 тактов
            for(uint32_t valueLimiter = 2; valueLimiter < 0x80000000; valueLimiter *= 2) {
                for(uint32_t j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
                    benchArray[j] = rand() & (valueLimiter - 1);
                }

                auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

#ifndef TESTING_STD_SORT
                radixSort(benchArray, benchArray + arraySize, sortedArray, convFunc, false);
#else
                std::sort(benchArray, benchArray + arraySize);
#endif

                auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

                totalTime += std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();
            }
        }

        std::cout << "O(" << arraySize << ")\t";
        
        // Для более красивого вывода
        if(arraySize < 10000) {
            std::cout << "\t";
        }

        std::cout << " = " << totalTime / (30 * samplesCount) << "us\n";

        arraySize *= 10;
    }

    delete[] benchArray;

    return 0;
}
```

На всякий напомню, что в случае обычных 32-разрядных чисел ( на которых этот алгоритм и тестируется ) поразрядная сортировка - линейный алгоритм, с небольшой константой.

Компилирую с помощью GCC 12.3 и флагом -O0 ( без оптимизаций ) и получаю следующую картину ( в секундах ):

| Размер массива | radixSort | std::sort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |
| 100 | 0.000004 | 0.000005 |
| 1000 | 0.000029 | 0.000082 |
| 10000 | 0.000302 | 0.001062 |
| 100000 | 0.003471 | 0.012800 |
| 1000000 | 0.045232 | 0.150556 |
| 10000000 | 3.410983 | 1.722028 |

На 10'000'000 значениях у `radixSort` огромная просадка по производительности. Я подозревал, что это может быть кэш процессора, т.к. значений уже очень много и, следовательно, я могу получать много промахов в кэше. Конкрентно мой процессор - `Intel Core i7 7740X 4.30GHz`, с 128КБ L1 кэша, 1МБ L2 кэша и 8МБ L3 кэша.

Однако, чтобы убедиться, что это **именно кэш**, я протестировал свой алгоритм на `Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 3.00GHz` c 64 Кб L1 кэша и 6МБ L2 кэша ( L3 отсутствует ) и получил уже следующее:

| Размер массива | radixSort | std::sort |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.000006 | 0.000000 |
| 100 | 0.000017 | 0.000009 |
| 1000 | 0.000135 | 0.000143 |
| 10000 | 0.001432 | 0.001841 |
| 100000 | 0.014908 | 0.022423 |
| 1000000 | 0.226156 | 0.264859 |
| 10000000 | 3.712056 | 3.046929 |

Почти все значения в 2-4 раза больше, но на 10'000'000 значениях у `radixSort` абсолютно такая же просадка с почти таким же временем, разве что на 0.3 секунды дольше, что, по моему мнению, странно, ведь на компьютере с этим процессором у меня **DDR3** память на частоте 1333МГц ( против моей **DDR4** на 2133МГц ).

Те же тесты, но с флагами `-O2 -march=core2`:

| Размер массива | radixSort/Core i7 | radixSort/Core 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.000001 | 0.000001 |
| 100 | 0.000002 | 0.000003 |
| 1000 | 0.000011 | 0.000029 |
| 10000 | 0.000133 | 0.000373 |
| 100000 | 0.001568 | 0.004818 |
| 1000000 | 0.027606 | 0.117099 |
| 10000000 | 3.021845 | 2.638910 |

В данном случае вообще получилось, что на 10'000'000 Core 2 оказался лучше, чем Core i7.

У меня алгоритм разделён на подготовку и саму сортировку ( в самом коде они визуально отделены специальными комментариями ), поэтому я решил замерить их отдельно, чтобы убедится, что обе части имеют просадки в производительности:

`-O2 -march=core2`

| Размер массива | подготовка/сортировка ( Core i7 ) | подготовка/сортировка ( Core 2 ) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.000000/0.000000 | 0.000000/0.000001 |
| 100 | 0.000000/0.000001 | 0.000000/0.000003 |
| 1000 | 0.000002/0.000008 | 0.000004/0.000025 |
| 10000 | 0.000020/0.000114 | 0.000041/0.000331 |
| 100000 | 0.000210/0.001347 | 0.000414/0.004375 |
| 1000000 | 0.002256/0.026568 | 0.006165/0.115193 |
| 10000000 | 0.073637/3.109803 | 0.064410/2.546230 |

Просадка как в подготовке, так и в сортировке, как и предполагалось.

Исходя из замеров я получаю, что на 10'000'000 **Core 2 Duo** если не быстрее **Core i7**, то уступает ему не сильно. Однако это не совсем вяжется с моим предположением о том, что просадка вызвана кэшем, ведь если это так, то, по идее, разница в скорости уже должна зависеть напрямую от частоты процессора и ОЗУ. В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос:

**Можно ли утверждать, что это всё же дело в кэше процессора, или дело может быть в чём-то другом?**

Я не знаток плюсов, и уж тем более могу чего-то не знать на уровне железа, однако у меня чистый интерес узнать хотя-бы на уровне теории ответ на этот вопрос, даже если ответ будет очень сложным.

##### UPD

Я решил детальнее изучить картину с построения, прежде всего, графиков.

Рассмотрим следующий кусок кода:

```cpp
for(uint32_t i = 0; i < samplesCount; i++) {
    for(uint32_t valueLimiter = 2; valueLimiter < 0x80000000; valueLimiter *= 2) {

        for(uint32_t j = 0; j < arraySize; j++) {
            benchArray[j] = rand() & (valueLimiter - 1); // rand() % valueLimiter
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

С помощью `valueLimiter` я ограничиваю значения, которые могут попасться в массиве, т.е. фактически оно определяет максимум.

Если замерить время исполнения в зависимости от значения `valueLimiter`, то можно получить следующую картину:

[image: общий график]

На этот раз я решил взять больше процессоров, большинство из которых - современные. Видно, что все процессоры имеют +- схожий по форме график, отличающийся лишь некой "константой", на которую они домножены. Один **Core 2 Duo** показывает линейную зависимость, выделяясь среди прочих.

Для тех, кому интересно, таблица размеров кэшей для процессоров:

| Процессор | L1 | L2 | L3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Core 2 E8400 | 64kb | 6mb | - |
| Core i7 2600K | - | 1mb | 8mb |
| Core i7 7740X | 128kb | 1mb | 8mb |
| Ryzen 9 3900X | 768kb | 6mb | 64mb |
| Ryzen 5 5600G | - | 3mb | 16mb |

У некоторых графиков есть `[RCM]` на конце. Под этими буквами подразумевается модификация кода в `radix.hpp`:

```cpp
for(uint64_t i = arraySize; i > 0; i--) {
    uint64_t idx = elements[i - 1].key[key];

    // Декрементируем сначала, а не в конце, чтобы получить индексы,
    // начинающиеся с 0
    counts[idx]--;

    elementBuffer[counts[idx]] = elements[i - 1];
}
```

Тут алгоритм читает `elements[i - 1].key[key]` от бОльших индексов к меньшим.
Как отметил @StanislavVolodarskiy, этот код не очень хорошо утилизирует кэш.

Обновлённая версия:

```cpp
#ifdef REDUCE_CACHE_MISS
// [RCM]

// Вот тут оптимизированная часть алгоритма, который хоть и идёт
// от бОльших индексов к меньшим, но читает по четыре элемента
// в удобном, прямолинейном для кэша формате.
uint64_t i = arraySize;

for(; i > 4; i -= 4) {
    element_t<T>& element3 = elements[i - 4];
    element_t<T>& element2 = elements[i - 3];
    element_t<T>& element1 = elements[i - 2];
    element_t<T>& element0 = elements[i - 1];

    uint64_t idx3 = element3.key[key];
    uint64_t idx2 = element2.key[key];
    uint64_t idx1 = element1.key[key];
    uint64_t idx0 = element0.key[key];

    counts[idx0]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx0]] = element0;

    counts[idx1]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx1]] = element1;

    counts[idx2]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx2]] = element2;

    counts[idx3]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx3]] = element3;
}

for(; i > 0; i--) {
    uint64_t idx = elements[i - 1].key[key];

    counts[idx]--;

    elementBuffer[counts[idx]] = elements[i - 1];
}

#else
// не [RCM]

for(uint64_t i = arraySize; i > 0; i--) {
    uint64_t idx = elements[i - 1].key[key];

    // Декрементируем сначала, а не в конце, чтобы получить индексы,
    // начинающиеся с 0
    counts[idx]--;

    elementBuffer[counts[idx]] = elements[i - 1];
}

#endif
```

Перейдём к анализу самой части сортировки. Замерим исполнение более маленьких участков кода.
Начнём с части распределения элементов по корзинам:

```cpp
for(uint64_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    counts[elements[i].key[key]]++;
}
```

Как указал @MBo, этот участок кода *беспощадно прыгает по памяти* и, отсюда, плохо кэшируется. Замеры:

[image: подсчёт]

Что интересно, оба процессора по-разному отрабатывают в этих ситуациях ( причём проверенно: компилятор не делает никаких оптимизаций для кэша ). **Core 2** показывает линейную зависимость, в то время как **Core i7** поступает как-то по-своему и сильно ему уступает ( видимо в попытках закешировать по-умному тратит много своего времени ).

Теперь, замерим часть записи элементов в отсортированном формате:

```cpp
#ifdef REDUCE_CACHE_MISS
// [RCM]

// Вот тут оптимизированная часть алгоритма, который хоть и идёт
// от бОльших индексов к меньшим, но читает по четыре элемента
// в удобном, прямолинейном для кэша формате.
uint64_t i = arraySize;

for(; i > 4; i -= 4) {
    element_t<T>& element3 = elements[i - 4];
    element_t<T>& element2 = elements[i - 3];
    element_t<T>& element1 = elements[i - 2];
    element_t<T>& element0 = elements[i - 1];

    uint64_t idx3 = element3.key[key];
    uint64_t idx2 = element2.key[key];
    uint64_t idx1 = element1.key[key];
    uint64_t idx0 = element0.key[key];

    counts[idx0]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx0]] = element0;

    counts[idx1]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx1]] = element1;

    counts[idx2]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx2]] = element2;

    counts[idx3]--;
    elementBuffer[counts[idx3]] = element3;
}

for(; i > 0; i--) {
    uint64_t idx = elements[i - 1].key[key];

    counts[idx]--;

    elementBuffer[counts[idx]] = elements[i - 1];
}

#else
// не [RCM]

for(uint64_t i = arraySize; i > 0; i--) {
    uint64_t idx = elements[i - 1].key[key];

    // Декрементируем сначала, а не в конце, чтобы получить индексы,
    // начинающиеся с 0
    counts[idx]--;

    elementBuffer[counts[idx]] = elements[i - 1];
}

#endif
```

Замеры:

[image: сортировка]

**Core i7** с `-DREDUCE_CACHE_MISS` ускорился в ~3 раза по сравнению с обычной версией, и на этот раз превосходит **Core 2 Duo**. Сам **Core 2** с такой оптимизацией перестал показывать линейную зависимость и его график стал похож на график **Core i7**.

Я также провёл замеры с `-DREDUCE_CACHE_MISS`, чтобы узнать, стал ли **Core i7** быстрее:

| Размер массива | radixSort/Core i7 | radixSort/Core 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.000000 | 0.000001 |
| 100 | 0.000001 | 0.000003 |
| 1000 | 0.000011 | 0.000025 |
| 10000 | 0.000132 | 0.000332 |
| 100000 | 0.001602 | 0.004240 |
| 1000000 | 0.029790 | 0.119448 |
| 10000000 | 2.157345 | 2.264135 |

На этот раз во всех тестах **Core i7** быстрее.

Из всех этих графиков напрашивается вывод о том, что система кэширования **Core 2** отличается от **Core i7**, однако, по всей видимости, она это делает несколько более прямым и топорным способом, от чего растёт линейно, а **Core i7** делает это умнее, рассчитывая на более частый, нежели на более общий, случай.

Получается, что если это действительно так, то ответом на мой вопрос

***Можно ли утверждать, что это всё же дело в кэше процессора, или дело может быть в чём-то другом?***

будет:

**Да, это дело в кэше, а конкрентно просто в другом подходе к кэшированию информации.**

а столь неожиданное превосходство **Core 2** перед **Core i7** заключается лишь
в более эффективном для данной ситуации подходе к кэшированию, несмотря на, казалось бы, логичное предположение о том, что современные процессоры должны отрабатывать лучше везде.

В итоге, вопрос можно сузить до следующего:

**Насколько данная теория может быть правдоподобна?**

Comment: Замеры времени без оптимизации не имеют никакого практического значения. А также: попробуйте заменить глобальную функцию `keyConverter` на lambda, она может быть лучше оптимизирована.

Comment: @AlexF замеры **c оптимизацией** я тоже привёл. Что насчёт лямбы - прирост в скорости конечно есть, но прям небольшой, в пределах погрешности даже ( +- пара микросекунд ) ,причём если передавать функцию как С-шный указатель - прирост будет ещё больше. Но всё это не сильно влияет на просадку при 10'000'000 значениях, что меня и интересует, но за оба хинта спасибо!

Comment: Вот эта строка `counts[elements[i].key[key]]++;` беспощадно прыгает по памяти. Не тестировали на уже отсортированных данных?

Comment: @MBo я поэтому и сетовал на кэш. Что насчёт теста на отсортированных данных - просадка у **Core i7** там же, лишь не такая сильная ( тогда реальное значение времени исполнения в 3 раза больше ожидаемого, против 10 раз в данных, которые я привёл в своём вопросе ), но на этот раз **Core 2** медленнее, чем **Core i7** ( хотя у **Core 2** просадки почти нет, у него видна чистая линия ).

Comment: `counts[idx]--;` - писать желательно слева направо. Быстрее будет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy в других ситуациях может быть и правда быстрее, но в данном что слева направо, что справа налево - генерируется одинаковый ассемблерный код.

Comment: Я говорю про использование кешей, которые лучше работают если адреса растут.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy про этот момент не совсем понял - имеется ввиду всё же про декремент, про порядок прохождения циклом или что-то другое?

Comment: Копировать данные из неупорядоченного массива в корзины лучше от младших индексов к старшим.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я может быть непонимаю очевидных вещей, может быть мы говорим о разных вещах, но тут никаких данных в корзины не копируется. Чтобы не было недопониманий по коду, сразу скажу по этой части: данный кусок кода что для `counts`, что для `elementBuffer` прыгает по памяти рандомно. Его цель - записать в `elementBuffer` отсортированный `elements` по текущему ключу. Как либо записывать данные ( как и читать их ) слева направо в любой из двух представленных массивов не представляется возможным, по крайней мере для меня.

Comment: Вы читаете исходный массив справа налево. Я  полагаю что аналогичный алгоритм, читающий исходный массив слева направо, будет быстрее работать из-за лучшего использования кешей.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вот теперь понял о чём вы. В данном случае на самом деле можно проходится по массиву с шагом 4, считывать последовательно `uint64_t idx4 = elements[i - 4].key[key]`, `uint64_t idx3 = elements[i - 3].key[key]` и т.д. в удобном для кэша формате и потом писать ( с такой оптимизацией этот участок кода ускоряется в среднем в 3 раза ). Если будут результаты по исследованию - обновлю вопрос и включу данный кусок кода.

Comment: Естественно, все дело в кэше. Это сразу видно при сравнении с std::sort (как известно, она реализует вариант mergesort, в которой большинство обращений к данным последовательно по памяти)

Comment: @avp я и подумал на кэш, но меня просто смутило, что **Core 2** в тестах отработал быстрее относительно современного **Core i7**, о чём я косвенно и спросил. А вот уже исследование, которое я провёл, дало мне мысль, почему **Core 2** мог отработать быстрее.